# Why is it showing so big size of files?

Tags: 12.04, storage

This is the screenshot of the properties of all files except /home:

[image: properties]

My whole hard disk is of ~320 GB, then how is it so big?

Comment: Have you started your graphical file manager as root for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the file `/proc/kcore` which for some reason looks so big. Just exclude `/proc` from your folders list to get a more realistic result.

`/proc/kcore` specifically is a file which maps directly to every available byte in your virtual memory. It is a system file, provided by the virtual `procfs` filesystem, and is not a real file.

Comment: This is good to know.